# Rails 3: As json with include option does not takes into account as_json redefinition for included association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I've got two models.

```
Class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :model_bs

end

Class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :model_a

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
       :whatever => 'hello world'
    }
  end

end
```

When I call `model_a.as_json(:include => :model_b)`, I want it to return a json which includes all model_bs, which it does, but employing my as_json redefinition, which it does not as it just uses the default one. Is there any way to use my own method rather than the original one? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3, as_json method invokes serializable_hash to obtain the attributes hash. And they share the same 'options' parameter. In your case, overwritting serializable_hash would give the expected result.

```
def serializable_hash(options = {})
  {:whatever => 'hello world'}
end
```

But, My suggestion is that instead of overwriting the convention, operate on the result of "super", which is like:

```
 def serializable_hash(options = {})
  hash = super
  has[:name] = "hello world"
  hash
end
```